# How to validate edittext with integers in android?

Tags: android, integer, android-edittext, validation

I want to have an `edittext` that only accepts numbers as input and when a button is clicked I want to check that the `edittext` has got a number inside and is not empty. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this in layout.xml

```
<EditText android:numeric="integer" ..../>
```

**in Code**

```
EditText  mNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id....);
```

onButtonClick

```
if(mNumber.getText().toString().length()>0)
//logic
else
//empty Editext
```

Comment: if the box is empty when the button is cliked it gives an error

Answer (score 0):

Call EditText.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

This will make sure that numeric virtual keypad will appear, and special filtering will be applied to only allow only numbers to be entered.

To check empty text, call
EditText.getText().length() != 0

Comment: EditText.getText().toString().length() is required

Comment: Paste is also filtered to numbers. It's internally done by TextView.setFilters with applied DigitsKeyListener, which won't let any non-digits characters into the text.

Comment: thats good, an you just edited your answer a lil so I can remove my downvote

Answer (score 0):

Instead of validating you can add a (inpuType = "number") attribute in your xml file (Under the editText) after which you'll be able to add only numbers in your editText.